# Spring Qualifier vs scope = prototype

Tags: spring, scope

Если не ошибаюсь, по умолчанию (в случае scope = singleton) в Spring невозможно создание двух бинов, производных от одного класса, но с разными значениями свойств. В этом случае мы столкнемся с org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Проблема решается дополнительным аннотированием инжектируемых бинов @Qualifier с аргументом - именем бина.

Три вопроса:

1. почему наличие такой аннотации избавляет от Exception (странный
   вопрос, согласен - можно ответить "так и было задумано, что обычно
   нельзя, но в такой комбинации можно". Если дело так и обстоит, приму
   такой ответ.
2. можно ли инжектировать в один и тот же класс два бина одного и то же интерфейса или класса с разными именами, вводимыми посредством
   @Qualifier
3. является ли эта аннотация аналогом scope=”prototype”? Если да, когда что использовать предпочтительнее. Если нет, пожалуйста,
   поясните разницу.  Prototype - это несколько экземпляров бина с полностью совпадающим набором свойств?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `@Qualifier` - это по сути уточняющая аннотация. Представь, что у тебя приложение, которое работает с двумя базами. При этом имена схем (бин класса `String`), по неким причинам, ты хочешь инъектить средствами spring. Тут возникает проблема, что у тебя будут созданы два бина с одним именем. Как раз тут и приходит на помощь `@Qualifier`. Создаешь два бина класса `String` и помечаешь один как `@Qualifier("schema1")`, а второй как `@Qualifier("schema2")`. Теперь всё будет работать. К слову, данной аннотацией можно помечать другие аннотации и тогда они тоже начнут работать как квалификаторы.
2. Да, см. пункт 1.
3. Цели данных аннотаций не пересекаются. Про `@Qualifier` я уже пояснил. `scope=”prototype”` означает, что на каждую точку инъекции бина данного класса spring будет создавать новый экземпляр бина. Иными словами, если у тебя есть класс `A`, у которого `scope=”prototype”`, и есть два бина классов `B` и `C`, каждый из которых содержит поле класса `A`, то spring создаст два экземпляра класса `A`, каждый из которых будет заинъекчен в соответствующий бин.